# button background image change

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a button's background picture.  I successfully add this code to make it work

```
<input type=submit name="y" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()" 
       title='press here if the Serial works' 
       style="background-color: black; border: 0px solid #900; 
              background: url(/ar/serials/images/work.png) repeat-x;
              width:100px; height:40px; margin-left: 50px;">
```

The question is, can I add any other code to the same line to change the background image `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following attributes:

```
onmouseover="this.style.background='url(image1.jpg)';"
onmouseout="this.style.background='url(image2.jpg)';"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

(you will need to replace the image urls with your own)

```html
<input type=submit name="y" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()" title='press here if the Serial works' onmouseover="this.style.background='url(http://placehold.it/100x40/000000/ffffff?text=1)';" onmouseout="this.style.background='url(http://placehold.it/100x40/ffffff/000000?text=1)';"
style="background-color: black; border: 1px solid #900; 
              background: url(http://placehold.it/100x40/ffffff/000000?text=1) repeat-x;
              width:100px; height:40px; margin-left: 50px;">
```